# Signals not getting caught in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with a custom class which emits a signal after fixed interval. This signal is emitting fine as I have connected it with a slot in the same class, and verified with the qdebug statements in slots. The problem is when I try to connect the same signals in mainwindow class, the slots are not being called.
Here is my code:

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "counter.h"
#include <QTextEdit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void updateText(int);
    void test(int);
    void anotherSlot();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Counter *cobj;
    int v;
    QTextEdit *te;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include "counter.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cobj = new Counter(this);

    v = 0;
    te = ui->textEdit;
    bool success1 = connect(cobj, SIGNAL (mileStoneReached(int)), this, SLOT(updateText(int)),Qt::AutoConnection);
    bool success2 = connect(cobj,SIGNAL (mileStoneReached(int)), this,SLOT(test(int)),Qt::AutoConnection);
    bool success3 = connect(cobj,SIGNAL (anotherSignal()), this,SLOT (anotherSlot()),Qt::AutoConnection);
    qDebug() << success1 << "   " << success2 << "  " << success3;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    cobj = new Counter();

    te->setText("0");
    qDebug() <<QThread::currentThreadId();
    cobj->run();
}

void MainWindow::updateText(int x)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    v = (v+1) * 13;
    te->setText(QString("%1").arg(v));
}

void MainWindow::test( int x)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    qDebug() <<"___" ;
}

void MainWindow::anotherSlot()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    qDebug() <<"__######_" ;
}
```

Counter.h

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H
#include <QTimer>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Counter(QObject *parent= nullptr);

    void run();
    void reset();
    void init();

signals:
    void mileStoneReached(int x);
    void anotherSignal();

public slots:
    void increment();
    void test();

private:
    int cValue;
    QTimer *timer;
};
#endif // COUNTER_H
```

Counter.cpp

```
#include "counter.h"
#include<QDebug>

Counter::Counter(QObject*parent):QObject(parent)
{
    cValue= 0;
    init();
}

void Counter:: init()
{
    timer=new QTimer;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(increment()),Qt::AutoConnection);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(mileStoneReached(int)), this,SLOT(test()),Qt::AutoConnection);
}

void Counter::reset()
{
    cValue=0;
}

void Counter::run()
{
    timer->start(100);
}

void Counter::increment()
{
    cValue++;
    if(cValue % 13 ==0)
    {
        qDebug() << cValue;
        emit mileStoneReached( cValue);
    }
    else
    {
        emit (anotherSignal());
    }
}

void Counter::test()
{
    qDebug() << "Signal caught";
}
```

Output:

```
true     true    true // all connections are fine
0x21ac // Main thread Id  irrelevant to problem
13 // counter value
Signal caught //qdebug  print
26
Signal caught
39
Signal caught
52
Signal caught
65
Signal caught
78
Signal caught
91
Signal caught
104
Signal caught
117
Signal caught
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `MainWindow` constructor you instantiate a `Counter*` and assign it to `cobj` but in `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked` you create yet another `Counter*` and again assign it to `cobj` and then run your counter, this creates several problems.

In `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked` when you create the new `Counter*` you have a memory leak since you never `delete` the previous instance, also you call `run` on the new instance but the connections have been created with the old one that was created inside the `MainWindow` constructor, so the connected methods won't ever be called.

A possible solution would be to just use the instance create inside the `MainWindow` constructor.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    te->setText("0");
    qDebug() <<QThread::currentThreadId();

    cobj->run();
}
```

You also never `delete` the `Counter*` inside `MainWindow`, this causes yet another memory leak, so add `delete cobj` in your `MainWindow` destructor.

I suggest to also change the various connections to use the new syntax by using function pointers.

```
connect(cobj, SIGNAL (mileStoneReached(int)), this, SLOT(updateText(int)),Qt::AutoConnection);
```

Becomes:

```
connect(cobj, &Counter::mileStoneReached, this, &MainWindow::updateText,Qt::AutoConnection);
```

This is safer since some checks are done at compile time, so for example if you make a typo in the function name it won't compile at all.

Comment: oops. How foolish i am!  Thanks SilvanoCerza, You have eyes of Hawk!